# Npm command doesn't work anymore

Tags: node.js, npm

Whenever I try to run the `npm` command I end up with the following:

```
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'readable-stream'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\decraejo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npmlog\node_modules\are-we-there-yet\index.js:2:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
```

I found this article, but their solution doesn't seem to work for me:
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6366

> @deepakvasa Very helpful advice! I've also met with this problem and solve it by remove node_modules and reinstall npm

Where should I remove the node_modules from?

Comment: I think they mean to remove this folder C:\Users\decraejo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules then reinstall npm

Comment: I'll give it a go!

Comment: That did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was due to an incorrect installation attempt of `npm` that I had attempted. Just go to: `"drive_name":\Users\"your_user_name"\AppData\Roaming\npm` and remove the `node_modules` folder. Then try again. Did it for me!

Cheers!